# How do I set the color of any banner?

Tags: java, bukkit

I'm trying to place down a banner with a specific color, but I keep getting a black one.

```
Block block;
// ...
block.setType(Material.STANDING_BANNER);
Banner banner = (Banner)block.getState();
banner.setBaseColor(DyeColor.RED);
```

Is there something wrong with this code, or is it a Bukkit bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call [`Banner.update()`](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/block/BlockState.html#update()).

> Attempts to update the block represented by this state, setting it to the new values as defined by this state.

```
Block block;
// ...
block.setType(Material.STANDING_BANNER);
Banner banner = (Banner)block.getState();
banner.setBaseColor(DyeColor.RED);
banner.update();
```